# How to retrieve an unused subnet from a list of input subnets

Tags: python, ip-address, subnet

I have a list as input

```
[
  "10.1.30.0", # to be considered as /24 by default
  "10.1.34.0/24",
  "10.2.0.0/16"
]
```

Which can be modified at any given time by user.

I want to write a function that returns the available `/24` subnet

```
mySubnets = [
  "10.1.30.0", # to be considered as /24 by default
  "10.1.34.0/24",
  "10.2.0.0/16"
]
usedCount = 0

def addToMySubnet(ipStr):
    mySubnets.add(ipStr)

def getAvailableSubnet():
   # here i want to iterate through list and get an available `/24` subnet
   usedCount += 1

def releaseSubnet():
   # to release a subnet, so that it can be re-used
   usedCount -= 1

def deleteSubnet(ipStr):
   # remove ipStr from mySubnets
   # remove a subnet from mySubnets, it can not be used on next call of getAvailableSubnet
```

Let's say from after above input, I make following `getAvailableSubnet` calls:

```
get1 : 10.1.30.0 # calling getAvailableSubnet 1st time, so get1
get2 : 10.1.34.0 # calling getAvailableSubnet 2nd time, so get2
get3 : 10.2.1.0
get4 : 10.2.2.0
release : 10.1.30.0 # i released the subnet that was received from get1
get5: 10.1.30.0 # the released subnet can be reused if it not removed from mySubnets.
add : 10.3.0.0/16 # this is addToMySubnet call
get6: 10.2.3.0
...
get256: 10.2.255.0
get259: 10.3.1.0
get260: 10.3.2.0
```

So my question is, what is the most efficient way to find the available subnet?

I am looking to use `ipaddress` lib on Python2.

Comment: Put your subnets in a `set`, and `pop` from the set to get a subnet, then `add` to the set when it becomes available again?

Comment: When you say `10.2.0.0/32`, do you mean `10.2.0.0/16`?

Comment: oh.. yes that `/16`. i will update

Comment: @L3viathan the set can be huge, as many as 255*255 .. thats not seems efficient

Comment: Then, in that case, wouldn’t there be 65,536 possible subnets for `10.2.0.0/16`? You seem to be using only 256 of them. (Actually fewer, since the numbers range from `get6` to `get256`.)

Comment: Is 255*255 huge...?  You can pop an item and add it back to a set containing 65536 items 10000000 times only in two seconds. Isn't it fast enough for you?

Comment: okay taking real scenario, how can i is persisting 255*255 into db (say mongodb), then whenever i need new subnet, i need to fetch mySubnets and also that list (set). So is updating it every time i need new subnet is a good idea.?